# Why is there 5 elements being created in my list? Need to create tally function. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

The main focus is within the JS, the 'add appointment' function is looping and the 'years' value ends up with a list of 5 elements even though only one appointnment is being made. I think two extra's are being created from the add appointment function, and another 2 are being created from the concurrent appointment function. This is for a group project, and i didn't do this component which is why im struggling to understand and fix this problem.

Im trying to push the yy variable into the years list, then create a tally function to list how many appointments are in each year.

Any advice is highly appreciated! and if I haven't elaborated enough please let me know! :)

Thanks in advance

```
    <html>

<head>
    <script>
        const MIN_YEAR = 2019;
        var years = [];
        var list = [];
        let appointment = {
            date: "",
            startTime: "",
            endTime: "",
            subject: "",
            venue: "",
            rowData: function () {
                return "<tr><td>" + this.date + "</td><td>" + this.startTime + "</td><td>" + this.endTime + "</td><td>" + this.subject + "</td><td>" + this.venue + "</td><td>" + this.priority + "</td></tr>";
            }
        }

        function addAppointment() {
            let newAppointment = Object.create(appointment);

            var startIndex = document.getElementById('startTime').selectedIndex;
            var priority;

            newAppointment.startTime = document.getElementById('startTime').options[startIndex].value;
            newAppointment.subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
            newAppointment.venue = document.getElementById('venue').value;


            if (validDate() != false) { newAppointment.date = validDate(); }

            if (validTime != false) { newAppointment.endTime = validTime(); }

            if (document.getElementById('medium').checked) { priority = medium.value; }

            else if (document.getElementById('low').checked) { priority = low.value; }

            else { priority = high.value; }

            newAppointment.priority = priority;

            if (validDate() === null | validDate() === undefined | validTime() === null | validTime() === undefined | validTime() === false | validDate() === false | isConcurrentAppointment(newAppointment.date, newAppointment.startTime, newAppointment.endTime) != true) {
                alert('Date or time entry invalid')
            }
            else {
                list.push(newAppointment);
                let tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
                tbody.innerHTML += newAppointment.rowData();
            }
        }

        function validDate() {
            var inputDate = document.getElementById('date').value
            var dateformat = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
            if (inputDate.match(dateformat)) {
                document.getElementById('date').focus();
                var opera1 = inputDate.split('/');
                var opera2 = inputDate.split('-');
                lopera1 = opera1.length;
                lopera2 = opera2.length;
                if (lopera1 > 1) {
                    var pdate = inputDate.split('/');
                }
                else if (lopera2 > 1) {
                    var pdate = inputDate.split('-');
                }
                var dd = parseInt(pdate[0]);
                var mm = parseInt(pdate[1]);
                var yy = parseInt(pdate[2]);
                years.push(yy);
                if (yy < MIN_YEAR) {
                    alert('Date is invalid.');
                    return error;
                }
                var daysInMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
                if (mm == 1 || mm > 2) {
                    if (dd > daysInMonths[mm - 1]) {
                        alert('Date is invalid.');
                        return error;
                    }
                }
                if (mm == 2) {
                    var lyear = false;
                    if ((!(yy % 4) && yy % 100) || !(yy % 400)) {
                        lyear = true;
                    }
                    if ((lyear == false) && (dd >= 29)) {
                        alert('Date is invalid');
                        return error;
                    }
                    if ((lyear == true) && (dd > 29)) {
                        alert('Date is invalid.');
                        return error;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                alert('Date is invalid.');
                document.getElementById('date').focus();
                return error;
            }
            return inputDate;
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
        function validTime() {
            var startIndex = document.getElementById('startTime').selectedIndex;
            var appStartTime = document.getElementById('startTime').options[startIndex].value;
            var endIndex = document.getElementById('endTime').selectedIndex;
            var endTime = document.getElementById('endTime').options[endIndex].value;
            if (endTime <= appStartTime) {
                alert("Appointment must end later than the start time.");
                return error;
            }
            return endTime;
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function isConcurrentAppointment(dateInput, startInput, endInput) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (dateInput == list[i].date) {
                    if (startInput.substring(0, 3) == list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) < list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) > list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) == list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) >= list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) > list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) > list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3) && startInput.substring(0, 3) < list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) > list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) < list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) < list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) < list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3) && endTime.substring(0, 3) > list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) > list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) <= list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3)
                        || startInput.substring(0, 3) > list[i].startTime.substring(0, 3) && endInput.substring(0, 3) == list[i].endTime.substring(0, 3)) {
                        alert('New appointments cannot start before previous one finishes');
                        return false
                    }
                    else
                        return true
                }
                else
                    return true
            }
            return true
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Tallying function:
        var i;

        //var yearArr = new Array(years[i]);

        function summary() {
            document.writeln('<table border="1">')
            document.writeln('<tr><th>Year</th><th>Count</th></tr>')
            for (i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
                document.writeln('<tr><td>' + years[i] + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + searchCount(years[i], years) + '</td></tr>')

            }
            document.writeln('</table>')


            function searchCount(targetValue, arr) {
                var count = 0; // Count of target value
                var i = 0;     // Iterative counter

                // Examine each element.
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if (arr[i] == targetValue)
                        count++;
                }
                return count;
            }
        }





    </script>

</head>




<body>

    <title>Diary</title>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Diary</h1>
    <form>
        <table bgcolor="#cccccc" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="date" name="date" size="10"></td>
                <td align="right">Start Time</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="startTime">
                        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                        <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                        <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                        <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                        <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                        <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                        <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td align="right">End Time</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="endTime">
                        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                        <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                        <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                        <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                        <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                        <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                        <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                    </select>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Subject:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="subject" size="10"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Venue:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="venue" size="10"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center">Priority</td>
                <td><input type="radio" id="high" name="Priority" value="High" checked="true" /> High<br />
                <td><input type="radio" id="medium" name="Priority" value="Medium" /> Medium<br />
                <td><input type="radio" id="low" name="Priority" value="Low" /> Low<br />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <tr>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Add Appointment" onclick="addAppointment()" /></td>
            </div>
        </tr>


        <hr>

        <div>
            <table align="center" width="80%" height="150px" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="1px" border="1" id="table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="50">Date</th>
                        <th width="20">Start</th>
                        <th width="20">End</th>
                        <th width="75">Subject</th>
                        <th width="60">Venue</th>
                        <th width="5">Priority</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody"> </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td><input type="reset" value="Randomise Appointments" onclick="shuffleAppointments()" /></td>
                <td></td><input type="button" value="Sort Appointments" onclick="sortRecords()" /></td>
                <td>by</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Date">
                        <option value="date">Date</option>
                        <option value="startTime">Start Time</option>
                        <option value="endTime">End Time</option>
                        <option value="subject">Subject</option>
                        <option value="venue">Venue</option>
                        <option value="priority">Priority</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <hr>




        <div style="text-align:left;">
            <td></td><input type="button" value="Summary" onclick="summary()" /></td>
            <td>by</td>
            <td>
                <select id="tallyOption">
                    <option value="year">Year</option>
                    <option value="date">Date</option>
                    <option value="optPriority">Priority</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        </hr>

    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling validDate() to make the comparison each time and inside the validDate function you are mutating the years variable.

There are multiple ways to fix it but in my opinion the first one and the most basic, which I strongly suggest, is to store the value of validDate() in a constant and make the further comparisons with it. You should always try to avoid calling the function each time. It's better to save its result in memory

Where you have

```
            if (validDate() != false) { newAppointment.date = validDate(); }
```

inside the addApointment function, just go for

```
const isDateValid = validDate()
```

and then replace all the upcoming ocurences (5) of validDate() with isDataValid

```
            const isDateValid = validDate()
            if (isDateValid != false) { newAppointment.date = isDateValid; }

and 

            if (isDateValid === null | isDateValid === undefined | validTime() === null | validTime() === undefined | validTime() === false | isDateValid === false | isConcurrentAppointment(newAppointment.date, newAppointment.startTime, newAppointment.endTime) != true) {
                alert('Date or time entry invalid')
            }
```

And of course I strongly suggest you to do the same for validTime.

Comment: the hero we need

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to come from appending to `years` within the `validDate` function, which is treated as a non-mutating function elsewhere in the code. Since `validDate` is repeatedly called within the `addAppointment` function every time tha value is needed, the `years.push(yy)` line will also be called repeatedly. You could move the `years.push(yy)` line elsewhere, but the better solution would be to change `addAppointment` so that it calls `validDate` and `validTime` once each, stores their values, and then performs the rest of the operations on the stored values. However, you might also want to move the `years.push(yy)` so that it is only called when an appointment is completely valid.

Comment: Awesome, where would the years.push(yy) get moved to stop it? if you dont mind me asking

Comment: Somewhere where no more errors can be thrown, so probably within the final `else` block of `addAppointment`. Since `yy` won't be defined there anymore, you will have to store it somewhere resettable until you reach that point.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your requirements are, but the `Date` constructor might prove to be a large simplification of your current code

Comment: hahaha i desperately wanted to use the date function but prof said no apparently. Thought it would be fine considering its what you'd use in the workplace but, go figure. Im sorry, what do you mean by store it somewhere resettable?

Comment: I guess I meant temporary. Whenever the tests fail, it shouldn't have an effect on the final state.

Comment: How would you do that im sorry? Still feeling lost

Comment: You have three options. 1) Copy `yy` into a global variable, and use that whenever you get to the correct location. 2) Add `yy` to the return values of the function (returning a list), and keep a local variable instead. You can use destructuring assignment for a clean seperation of the list. 3) Reparse the year from the date whenever you need it, repeating some of the logic from `validDate`.